# Error using Python Console in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am using QGIS version 3.2.2-Bonn on Windows 10 and this is my first attempt using Python on QGIS from the console. I am following this article: 
[Getting Started With Python Programming](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html)

When typing `iface` in the console a receive the following reply:

```
qgis._gui.QgisInterface object at 0x0000019EF2194D38
```

Then when I try to use the `dir(layer)` command I receive the following error message:

```
*dir(layer)*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'layer' is not defined
```

Do I need to configure something before starting using the console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `iface` is predefined variable in QGIS. `qgis._gui.QgisInterface object at ....` means that variable `iface` is an instance of `QgisInterface`.
- You probably didn't define variable `layer`. Thus, you get an error. In the article there is a line `layer = iface.activeLayer()` above the `dir(layer)`. Firstly, run that code (please be sure to select a layer before), then you can use `dir(layer)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first define the `layer` first click on **`Layer`**=>**`Vector-Layer`**=>**`Upload`** the **.shp** file and then select the `identity tool` and you will see the features and value corresponding to the layer points.

After this write

`layer = iface.activeLayer()
 dir(layer)`

After this start using features and then you can do `attribute-based` **clustering** and `statistical analysis`.